# <character*> only appends last input using cin

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I'm using a vector to store `char*` in the array by getting user input using cin. The input is received in a loop and everything works fine until I display the input. The last element that is put in the vector is displayed in all of the indexes.ie.if I put the string "hello" "world" "this' "is" "C++" using cin in a loop. The output is "C++" 5 times.

The code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *str=new char[10];
    vector<char*> vec;
    int i=0;

    for( i=0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        cout<<"Enter string: ";
        cin>>str;
        vec.push_back(str);
    }

    for( i=0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the code when ran]

Comment: use std::string instead char*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the string with every input.

```
char *str=new char[10];
```

creates one c-style string.  Then

```
cin>>str;
```

Fills it contents.  When you do

```
vec.push_back(str);
```

You copy a pointer to that string an put it into the vector.  Then when you loop again it overwrites `str` with what you input next.  Since all of the vector elements still point to the same string they will all have the same data.

What you needs is a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and then you can use

```
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    vector<std::string> vec;
    int i=0;

    for( i=0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        cout<<"Enter string: ";
        cin>>str;
        vec.push_back(str);
    }

    for( i=0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vec.push_back(str);
```

You are putting same address to the vector over and over again.

You will need to move this:

```
char *str=new char[10];
```

inside the loop.

And then not forget to call `delete` on each vector element.

As stated in comments, `std::string` is probably a better choice.

Comment: is there anyway i can add data without modifying the same address?

Comment: @Hawk Added suggestion, but you are better off using string class instead probably